# Is there a library which can show a popup menu like company's menu?

Tags: popup, gui

So I give it a list of items and it shows the menu at point, handles up/down keys automatically, so it works like the company menu. I looked into company's code, but apparently it implements the menu itself. Is there a separate package for such a menu UI only?

[image]

Comment: I think that `popup-el` can be a candidate: https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Though the repo is not very active. Last commit was 4 years ago.

Comment: @Philopolis: Please consider posting that as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time.